# how to bind 2 table dynamic data in bar chart using ajax call in mvc c#?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to show last 7 days count in the bar charts.for that I am using bar charts and asp.net mvc c#.I have created store procedure that return 2 tables form the database. Now in this page I can able to  show 1st table data.But no idea about how to show  2nd table data in the chart. Find table structure below

This is my 1st return table data =>

```
DateColumn | Count
09-05-2017    10
08-05-2017    05
07-05-2017    20
06-05-2017    4000
05-05-2017    30
04-05-2017    5000
03-05-2017    40
```

This is my 2nd table data =>

```
DateColumnForManual | TotalCountForManual
09-05-2017             10
08-05-2017             05
07-05-2017             20
06-05-2017             4000
05-05-2017             30
04-05-2017             5000
03-05-2017              40
```

This is my Class in c# =>

```
  public class Dashboard
  {
    public string DateColumn { get; set; }

    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    public string DateColumnForManual { get; set; }

    public int TotalCountForManual { get; set; }
 }
```

This is my status class=>

```
public class Status
{
    public bool Result { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }        
}
```

This is my Server side method =>

```
public JsonResult GetCount()
    {
            Dashboard objDashboard = new Dashboard();
            var Count = objDashboard.GetDashboard();
            return Json(new { data = Count.Data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
    }
```

This My Dashboard.cs =>

```
 public Status GetDashboard()
     {
        Status Status = new Status();            
            DataSet ds = DataAccess.ExecuteDataset(Settings.ConnectionString(), "spGetDashboard");

            if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                List<Dashboard> ListActivity = new List<Dashboard>();
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++) // this is my 1st table return 
                {
                    Dashboard objActivity = new Dashboard();
                    objActivity.DateColumn = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DateColumn"].ToString();
                    objActivity.TotalCount = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TotalCount"]);
                    ListActivity.Add(objActivity);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.tables[1].rows.count; i++) // this is my 2nd table return
                {
                   Dashboard objactivity = new Dashboard();
                   objactivity.datecolumnformanual = ds.tables[1].rows[i]["datecolumnformanual"].tostring();
                   objactivity.totalcountformanual = convert.toint32(ds.tables[1].rows[i]["totalcountformanual"]);
                   listactivity.add(objactivity);
                }
                Status.Data = ListActivity;
                Status.Result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Status.Result = false;
            }           
        return Status;
    }
```

here my ajax call =>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {        
$.ajax({
    url: 'Home/GetCount',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    delay: 15,
    success: function (data) {
          var arrlable = new Array();
            var arrdata = new Array();
            var arrdataForManual = new Array();

            for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                arrlable.push(data.data[i].DateColumn);
                arrdata.push(data.data[i].TotalCount);
                //arrdataForManual.push(data.data[i].TotalCountForManual);
            }
            AutoFollow(arrlable, arrdata);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

});

```
 function AutoFollow(arrlable, arrdata)
 {
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: arrlable, // here show date
        datasets: [{
            label: 'AutoFollow',
            data: arrdata
            backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,1)"
        }, {
            label: 'Manual',
            data: [30, 29, 5, 5, 20, 3, 10], // here i want to show 2nd table data
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,1)"
        }]
    },            
});
}
```

[image]

here in the sketch i am show autofollow count is dynamic show i want also want manual count from the database and this come from 2nd tabel data.

here above i show the my whole code and i want to show my 2nd table data in the bar charts any one have the idea how can do that please let me?

Comment: instead of putting all your code, please describe the scenario well.Then may be we can help you

Comment: mean you want to show also bar chart?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV see i am add sketch now any idea about this how can do that?

Comment: not exactly, I am unclear about your requirement.

Comment: i am see in my chart two column 1st is autofollow and 2nd is manual so now in my chart 1st autofollow data is a dynamic now and 2nd for data is static so i want to this 2nd column want to also dynamic.

Comment: ok, I guess your storedprocedure will return both table values, so it should be two dataset. You can do the same thing as you did for autofollow.Get second table details and get it in an ajax request( you can get both result in same ajax respose) and pass it to your javascript fucntion

Comment: yes and i want to just date in the sketch so how can do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143839/discussion-between-arunprasanth-kv-and-coderwill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could add another parameter to your **AutoFollow** function. This addition parameter will store manual data. Your script could look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/GetCount',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        delay: 15,
        success: function (data) {
                var arrlable = new Array();
                var arrdata = new Array();
                var arrdataForManual = new Array();

                for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                    if (data.data[i].DateColumn && data.data[i].DateColumn != "") {
                        arrlable.push(data.data[i].DateColumn);
                        arrdata.push(data.data[i].TotalCount);
                    } else {
                        arrdataForManual.push(data.data[i].TotalCountForManual);
                    }
                }
                AutoFollow(arrlable, arrdata, arrdataForManual);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});

 function AutoFollow(arrlable, arrdata, arrdataForManual)
 {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: arrlable, // here show date
        datasets: [{
            label: 'AutoFollow',
            data: arrdata,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,1)"
        }, {
            label: 'Manual',
            data: arrdataForManual,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,1)"
        }]
        },            
    });
}
```

Comment: yes i want to like this data but in my sketch date is full return with also time and in my database just return date and here c# side return whole date so i want to just get date so how can do that?any idea

Comment: If you want to get only Date part, you could do it inside C# function **GetDashboard**: objActivity.DateColumn = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DateColumn"].ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");    objActivity.DateColumnForManual  = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i]["DateColumnForManual"].ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");